# Flutter Fetch Data From API snapshot.hasError

Tags: flutter, snapshot

Now I try to fetch data from the pexels.com photos api. and I successfully finished this work on last month. Now i update my flutter version and run this code again. But now this code comes the error.

It always shows **snapshot.hasError**

### My Packages

```
import 'dart:convert';
import '../widgets/gridPhotos.dart';
import '../models/photoSearchModel.dart'; //used to decode json by https://app.quicktype.io 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

### Stateful Widget

```
class WallpaperScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WallpaperScreenState createState() => _WallpaperScreenState();
}

class _WallpaperScreenState extends State<WallpaperScreen> {
  int page = 1;
  PhotoSearchModel jsonPhotoHTTPGet;
  List<Photo> photos = List<Photo>();
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    getWallpapers("wallpaper", page);
    super.initState();
    _sc.addListener(() {
      if (_sc.position.pixels == _sc.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        getWallpapers("wallpaper", page);
      }
    });
  }
```

### function for fetch data from pexels api

```
  getCatergoryListWallpapers(int pageNo) async {
    await http.get(
      "https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=${widget.catergoryName}&per_page=50&page=${pageNo.toString()}",
      headers: {
        "Authorization":
            "Auth Token" // Auth Token Works 100%
      },
    ).then((value) {
      jsonPhotoHTTPGet = photoSearchModelFromJson(value.body);
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(value.body);
      jsonData["photos"].forEach((element) {
        Photo photosModel = new Photo();
        photosModel = Photo.fromJson(element);
        photos.add(photosModel);
        print(element);
      });
      setState(() {
        page++;
      });
    });
    return photos;
  }
```

### Future Builder Widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: getCatergoryListWallpapers(page),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: ListView.separated(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              controller: _scrollController,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 10.0,
                  height: double.infinity,
                );
              },
              itemCount: photos.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                      // My Code Goes Here
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child:Icon(
                  Icons.error_outline,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 60,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

If i run this code this return the Error Outline Icon
and this code is comes from the Future Builder elseif(snapshot.hasError){/* Icon Code */}

```
Icon(
  Icons.error_outline,
  color: Colors.red,
  size: 60,
),
```

### PhotoSearch.dart

```
// Using app.quicktype.io
import 'dart:convert';

PhotoSearchModel photoSearchModelFromJson(String str) =>
    PhotoSearchModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String photoSearchModelToJson(PhotoSearchModel data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class PhotoSearchModel {
  PhotoSearchModel({
    this.totalResults,
    this.page,
    this.perPage,
    this.photos,
    this.nextPage,
  });

  int totalResults;
  int page;
  int perPage;
  List<Photo> photos;
  String nextPage;

  factory PhotoSearchModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      PhotoSearchModel(
        totalResults: json["total_results"],
        page: json["page"],
        perPage: json["per_page"],
        photos: List<Photo>.from(json["photos"].map((x) => Photo.fromJson(x))),
        nextPage: json["next_page"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "total_results": totalResults,
        "page": page,
        "per_page": perPage,
        "photos": List<dynamic>.from(photos.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "next_page": nextPage,
      };
}

class Photo {
  Photo({
    this.id,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.url,
    this.photographer,
    this.photographerUrl,
    this.photographerId,
    this.avgColor,
    this.src,
    this.liked,
  });

  int id;
  int width;
  int height;
  String url;
  String photographer;
  String photographerUrl;
  int photographerId;
  String avgColor;
  Src src;
  bool liked;

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Photo(
        id: json["id"],
        width: json["width"],
        height: json["height"],
        url: json["url"],
        photographer: json["photographer"],
        photographerUrl: json["photographer_url"],
        photographerId: json["photographer_id"],
        avgColor: json["avg_color"],
        src: Src.fromJson(json["src"]),
        liked: json["liked"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "width": width,
        "height": height,
        "url": url,
        "photographer": photographer,
        "photographer_url": photographerUrl,
        "photographer_id": photographerId,
        "avg_color": avgColor,
        "src": src.toJson(),
        "liked": liked,
      };
}

class Src {
  Src({
    this.original,
    this.large2X,
    this.large,
    this.medium,
    this.small,
    this.portrait,
    this.landscape,
    this.tiny,
  });

  String original;
  String large2X;
  String large;
  String medium;
  String small;
  String portrait;
  String landscape;
  String tiny;

  factory Src.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Src(
        original: json["original"],
        large2X: json["large2x"],
        large: json["large"],
        medium: json["medium"],
        small: json["small"],
        portrait: json["portrait"],
        landscape: json["landscape"],
        tiny: json["tiny"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "original": original,
        "large2x": large2X,
        "large": large,
        "medium": medium,
        "small": small,
        "portrait": portrait,
        "landscape": landscape,
        "tiny": tiny,
      };
}
```

Now my Question is Why this code not works after the **flutter upgrade** ?

and Always Return Snapshot error.

In my Debug Console Says

```
E/flutter (12657): 
E/flutter (12657): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
E/flutter (12657): Receiver: null
E/flutter (12657): Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic) => Null)
E/flutter (12657): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (12657): #1      _WallpaperScreenState.getWallpapers (package:wallpaperworld/screens/wallpaperScreen.dart:39:24)
E/flutter (12657): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12657): 
E/flutter (12657): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter (12657): Receiver: null
E/flutter (12657): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Photo)
E/flutter (12657): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (12657): #1      new PhotoSearchModel.fromJson (package:wallpaperworld/models/photoSearch.dart:29:49)
E/flutter (12657): #2      photoSearchModelFromJson (package:wallpaperworld/models/photoSearch.dart:4:22)
E/flutter (12657): #3      _CategoryListViewBuilderState.getCatergoryListWallpapers.<anonymous closure> (package:wallpaperworld/widgets/categoryPhotos.dart:73:26)
E/flutter (12657): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (12657): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (12657): #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:152:18)
E/flutter (12657): #7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:704:45)
E/flutter (12657): #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:733:32)
E/flutter (12657): #9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:539:5)
E/flutter (12657): #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:254:13)
E/flutter (12657): #11     _withClient (package:http/http.dart)
E/flutter (12657): <asynchronous suspension>
```

And

```
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart': Failed assertion: line 3709 pos 15: 'left == null || right == null || width == null': is not
true.
```

Comment: paste `getCatergoryListWallpapers` method or `print(snapshot.data)`.What you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So, I tried accessing the API using your key and everything and it gives the following error:

```
{
    "error": "Rate limit exceeded"
}
```

One recommendation is to not provide your key like this in your questions. The second is to fix the error on the API end. It is not a Flutter error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely that your auth token has expired, they have a limited life expectancy (for security reasons).

Thats my guess, if you want to have more details you should print the error.

You can also try to add connectionState condition before hasError:

```dart
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active && snapshot.hasError)
```